# Insert headers of a datatable VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need your help for my code vb
In fact, i created an new datatable and i want to copy the headers from another datatable
here is my code

```
Dim name(de.Tables(0).Columns.Count) As String
    Dim p As Integer = 0
    For Each column As DataColumn In de.Tables(0).Columns
        name(p) = column.ColumnName
        p += 1
    Next
    Dim m As Integer = 0
    For m = 0 To de.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        dt.Columns(m).ColumnName = name(p)
    Next
```

Comment: You probably want to create new columns and add them, not just set a name; there is also DataType to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to "copy" the schema of a `DataTable`(so the columns and constraints) without it's content(`DataRows`) you can use [`DataTable.Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Dim clonedTable As DataTable = originalTable.Clone()
```

If you also want to copy the `DataRows` you have to use [`DataTable.Copy`](http://DataTable.Clone%60).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim name(de.Tables(0).Columns.Count) As String
     For Each column As DataColumn In de.Tables(0).Columns
             dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(column.ColumnName))
      Next
```